# Calendar refresh after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, calendar

I have a calendar, which pulls a bunch of dates which get highlighted, via an AJAX call. It all works fine. I have outputted the code below:

HTML for calendar:

```
                          <!-- Responsive calendar - START -->
                            <div class="responsive-calendar">
                            <div class="controls" style="height: 60px">
                                <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Prev</div></a>
                                <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
                                <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Next</div></a>
                            </div><hr/>
                            <div class="day-headers">
                              <div class="day cal-header">Sun</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Mon</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Tue</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Wed</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Thu</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Fri</div>
                              <div class="day cal-header">Sat</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="days" data-group="days">

                            </div>
                            </div>
                          <!-- Responsive calendar - END -->
```

**JS to load the calendar:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            bookedDates = bookedDates.concat(response),
            //bookedDates.toString;
            events = {};

            for (i = 0; i < bookedDates.length; i++) {
                events[bookedDates[i]] = {};
            }
            $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
                time: currentDate,
                events: events,
                startFromSunday: true,
                monthChangeAnimation: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Additionally, i have a form which submits new dates to highlight on the calendar via AJAX. Again, it works fine, but i am struggling to understand the best way to refresh JUST the calendar on an Ajax success. Can anyone assist? Do i just reload the "responsive-calendar" div, or do i need to somehow re-execute the script that populates the calendar above?

Thanks

Comment: Clear the calendar and reload with that code? I don't think your plugin has a method for adding events after initialization.

Comment: Ok, that points me in the right direction for what i need to do next. I'll working on building that method. Thanks